# Cannot execute a command with 'init' in it without triggering /sbin/init

Tags: linux, npm

so I have this node package I want to run with npx, the command is the following:

```
npx @pika/init --help
```

This should just download the package, execute it, and print the help.

What it does, however, is try to execute `/sbin/init`.

I've tried this on my Desktop running Arch, up to date, a server running Ubuntu 18.04, and another server running CentOS 6.10 - all exhibiting the same behavior.

I've also tried surrounding the argument in quotes or escaping the `/`, neither of which worked.

Anyone know whats going on here and how I can avoid it?

Thanks!

Oh and for what its worth I was using bash as my shell on all three systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is described by the [official npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx):

"By default, npx will check whether  exists in $PATH, or in the local project binaries, and execute that. If  is not found, it will be installed prior to execution."

In your case, this simply means that anything installed locally in `$PATH` has precedence over any remote packages.

You can use the option `--ignore-existing` to ignore existing binaries in `$PATH`, or in the local project. This forces `npx` to do a temporary install and use the latest version.

The resulting command looks like this:

```
npx --ignore-existing @pika/init --help
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!